# How to change fonts in react-pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, npm, fonts

I have a problem with changing fonts in react-pdf.

```
   // Register Font
Font.register({
  family: "Roboto",
  src:
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ink/3.1.10/fonts/Roboto/roboto-light-webfont.ttf"
});
```

So by default with font register is given Roboto font, but I need a Public Sans font and nowhere I can find source of it. Any help would be great

Comment: Not sure if I get you right, but you can download fonts from Google Fonts, e.g. Public Sans from here: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Public+Sans

Comment: @Tim yea, but using typescript it doesn't allow me to call font from local folder. Only way I found is to install font from npmjs but now I have no idea how to include it

Comment: Yeah the font needs to be downloadable, what I'm doing is to upload the fonts to AWS S3, but this would also work with any other service. So you could also create a public Github Repository, add the font files and use the raw URL from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to download the font ttf file and import it and assign to scr.

```
enter code here
```

import roboto from './Roboto-Regular.ttf'

`Font.register({ family: 'Roboto', fonts: [ { src: roboto , fontWeight: 'bold' } ] })`